# SymPy for solving a system of equations and substitution of symbols by numeric values

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am using the `SymPy` package (I wouldn't mind to use any other package if it works) to solve a system of equations. The system of equations contains the imaginary unit `I` and some coefficients `p,q,r,c,w` as constants of the variables `n` and `N`. I am interested in solving the system with these constant coefficients for a further evaluation. The code that I wrote is:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import re, im, I, E, symbols

I = complex(0,1)
p = sym.symbols('p', real=True)
q = sym.symbols('q', real=True)
r = sym.symbols('r', real=True)
c = sym.symbols('c', real=True)
w = sym.symbols('w', real=True)

n, N = sym.symbols('n, N')
Eq1 = sym.Eq(p*n-q*(N*r-n)-c + w*n*I, 0)
Eq2 = sym.Eq(q*(N*r-n) + w*N*I, 0)
Sol = sym.solve([Eq1, Eq2], (n, N))

n = sym.simplify(Sol[n])
N = sym.simplify(Sol[N])

n_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(n))
n_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(n))
N_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(N))
N_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(N))

p=1
q=1
r=1
c=1

print('Re(n) =', n_real)
print('Im(n) =', n_imag)
```

which gives as output:

```
Re(n) = c*(q*r*(p*q*r - w**2) + w**2*(p + q*r + q))/(w**2*(p + q*r + q)**2 + (p*q*r - w**2)**2)
Im(n) = c*w*(p*q*r - q*r*(p + q*r + q) - w**2)/(w**2*(p + q*r + q)**2 + (p*q*r - w**2)**2)
```

This is in agreement with the solution that i get by hand-solving it.
However, I would like to know how to replace the coefficients `p,q,r,c` by numerical values, e.g. =1 as in the code. Unfortunately I always get an output with symbolic coefficients but not numeric.

Does anyone knows what am I missing with this package? Any other package that can deal with this task/problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `n_real.subs({p:1.234, q:5.567}).simplify()` to substitute and simplify. With `... .evalf()` you convert a constant expression to floats. Without `evalf()` square roots etc. stay unevaluated, as sympy prefers exactness.

Comment: I suggest reading the sympy tutorial if you are unclear on basics like substitution: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Note that the solution given by solve in terms of symbolic parameters is valid for non-denegerate values of the parameters. In degenerate cases you would need to substitute the values before calling solve.